# Mysql connect to PDO convert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to convert a script into PDO connection but need help with this part of the script. I've done most part but em stuck with this part as I have to swap that array and get it to session.

```
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
    case "add":
        if(!empty($_POST["quantity"])) {
            $productByCode = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM tooted WHERE kood='" . $_GET["code"] . "'");;


            $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

            if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["code"],$_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["code"] == $k)
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = $_POST["quantity"];
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
            }
        }
    break;
    case "remove":
        if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
            foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                    if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
                    if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
            }
        }
    break;
    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
    break;  
}
}
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Can't use PDO as array  "Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array"  $itemArray = array($productByCode[0]["code"]=>array('name'=>$productByCode[0]["name"], 'code'=>$productByCode[0]["code"], 'quantity'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$productByCode[0]["price"]));

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::query` returns an object of type `PDOStatement`, which really has no analogue in the old `mysql_*` API. As the error message says, it's an object, not an array; it really works more like a cursor in a MySQL stored procedure, meaning that the only way to get data out is to call one of its `fetch*` methods. In your case this would be `PDOStatement::fetchAll`, which returns an array containing all rows of the result.

Incidentally, one of the reasons to switch to `PDO` is the availability of *prepared statements*, which help protect against the sort of [SQL injection attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1%7C32.9588) to which your current code is particularly vulnerable. Prepared statements automagically handle the correct quoting, escaping and type-matching of variables inserted into the query. The relevant code would be

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tooted WHERE kood = :code";
$stmt = $handler->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':code' => $)GET['code']));
$productByCode = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This sets `$productByCode` to a numeric array of rows, with each row an associative array.

If you know the result will contain only a single row, you could instead use

```
$productByCode = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

which returns a single row as an associative array.

There are, of course, opportunities for error handling, but I leave those as an exercise for the reader.

Hope that helps.